# How to create an element with text in between the element tags

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have made this function:

```
protected function _addElement($xmlDocument, $elementName, $parentElement){
    $element = $xmlDocument->createElement($elementName);
    return $parentElement->appendChild($element);
}
```

and I call it, i.e., in this way:

```
$Street = $this->_addElement($xmlDocument, 'Steet', $xmlDocument);
$House = $this->_addElement($xmlDocument, 'House', $Street);
```

and in the created XML document I will have it looking like that:

```
<Street>
   <House //maybe some attributes />
</Street>
```

So, the `createElement($elementName)` function is from the DOM API, that I call upon the DOM object `$xmlDocument` and it will create a closed node. What I need is to use a function that, with which I will get to the following result:

```
<Street>
   <Yard> the dog pooped all over the backyard </Yard>
</Steet>
```

I looked in the DOM API for something involving text, etc. I stumbled upon `createTextNode($content)` but that is something kinda' different, or maybe I just didn't understand correctly, when I read the documentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using [DOMDocument::createElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php), you'll notice from the method definition that it has a 2nd non-mandatory argument:

```
public DOMElement DOMDocument::createElement ( string $name [, string $value ] )
```

Just update your code to:

```
protected function _addElement($xmlDocument, $elementName, $elementValue, $parentElement) {
    $element = $xmlDocument->createElement($elementName, $elementValue);
    return $parentElement->appendChild($element);
}
```

and:

```
$Street = $this->_addElement($xmlDocument, 'Steet', 'My street', $xmlDocument);
$House  = $this->_addElement($xmlDocument, 'House', 'My house', $Street);
```

That way you'll be able to add elements with the values you want. Remember that if you want to add attributes to the newly created elements you'll have to use the [DOMDocument::createAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php) function on the `$element` variable before calling `appendChild`.

Comment: Thanks for hint about the value, I didn't think about this. 
About the attributes - I am using the `setAttribute($name, $value)` function from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for poiting out my copy+paste typo on the $elementName variable. Don't really know why your revision was rejected by others SO members though :|